# Get undefined in click function

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I use react js for my application.
I have a function which is called when I click on the button.

```js
const click = () => {
  dispatch(postData)
  console.log(selector.createUser.error.message;)
}
```

When I click on button submit i want to get the error message in `console.log(selector.createUser.error.message;)` , but i get undefined, and if i click second time i get the message. 
Why it is happening and ho to solve? How to get the exact value in click function clicking first time?

Comment: Can you tell us which part of ```selector.createUser.error.message;``` is undefined?
Is it the ```selector``` or the ```selector.createUser``` or the ```selector.createUser.error``` or the ```selector.createUser.error.message```?

Comment: @Amel, selector.createUser.error is undefined

Answer (score -2):

```js
const click = () => {
  dispatch(postData);
  console.log({selector.createUser.error.message});
}
```

Something like that should work. Depending on what `selector` is.

Note: this snippet doesn't actually work since nothing is defined but this shows how you would log a variable.